# How to prove that $A^{q+2}=A^2$ for non-invertible matrices A in the matrix ring $M_2(Z /(p))$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

This is a question from Jacobson's Basic Algebra I section 2.6. Let $A\in M_2(\mathbb{Z}/(p))$, $q=(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$, I managed to prove that if $A$ is invertible then $A^q=1$, thus $A^{q+2}=A^2$. However, how to prove this equation when $A$ is not invertible?

Comment: hint: if $\text{rank}(A)=1$ then either $A^2=\mathbf 0$ or $A$ is diagonalizable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is $A^{q+2}=A^2$ in $M_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158932/is-aq2-a2-in-m-2-mathbbz-p-mathbbz) (first hit [on Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24A%5E%7Bq%2B2%7D%3DA%5E2%24&p=1))

Comment: Oh yes, thank you for the redirection.